# (iOS) Drag and drop, Snap to grid, Check proper area

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

I've read all the stuff about drag'n'drop and `gestureRecognizer` but haven't found the solution.
I got "gamefield" *10x10* and I want to implement drag'n'drop with snap to grid and check if element placed on "gamefield".

I got my 8 "TempButtons" added to `UIView` buttonsSuperView with `action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:)`.

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UIControl *control = sender;
    originalPosition = [self getButton:sender];

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    point = [touch locationInView:control];

    float step = 31.0; // Grid step size.
    CGPoint center = control.center;
    center.x += step * floor((point.x / step));
    center.y += step * floor((point.y / step));

    control.center = center;
}
```

It works, I can move any button with grid step 31px. I can place it everywhere, but I have to put it on `UIView` fieldView. If it placed right there it's OK and I can replace it on another tile. But if I place it outside fieldView the button should return on its place. Something like this:

```
if ([self.fieldView pointInside:point withEvent:nil])
{
    control.center = center;
} else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^ {
                         control.center = originalPosition;
                         // to
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

If this code placed on `- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)` event method it makes button get back to its "originalposition" all the time its moving. But I need to check if its placed properly only on 'touchesEnded'. But that's another method and I don't understand how to realize which button pressed and its original coords to get back if placed improperly.

Maybe there's a better way to use 'UIView' instead of 'UIButton' but I still don't understand how to do that.

Thanks in advance. 
Kind Regards,

Nick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since no one answered my question I've spent some time and found working solution.

```
- (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    dragObject = sender;
    originalPosition = [self getButton:sender];

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    point = [touch locationInView:dragObject];

    float step = 31.0; // Grid step size.
    CGPoint center = dragObject.center;
    center.x += step * floor((point.x / step));
    center.y += step * floor((point.y / step));

    dragObject.center = center;

    [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(touchesEnded:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (![fieldView pointInside:dragObject.center withEvent:nil])
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^ {
                             dragObject.center = CGPointMake(originalPosition.x + 15.5, originalPosition.y + 15.5);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
    }
}
```

Now it works like charm and I can move along. My buttons moving freely snapped to grid and when pleced outside game field they move back to their original position.

Regards,
Nick